# Facebook Like button fb:admins cannot be parsed with type:'website'

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having trouble with the Facebook like button on my website. When a user clicks the like button it does everything correct, except post to their wall. I think I have narrowed it down to my fb:admins id because on the Facebook debugger gives me this warning:

Object at URL 'http://www.educatorcorkboard.com' of type 'website' is invalid because the given value 'educatorcorkboard' for property 'fb:admins' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'.

I know that my id is correct because my Facebook page is https://www.facebook.com/educatorcorkboard

My meta tags are as follows:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="educatorcorkboard"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Free Math Worksheets"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.educatorcorkboard.com"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.educatorcorkboard.com/Banner2.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Educator Corkboard"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Educator Corkboard is a site for math teachers to     find worksheets, activities, and games for secondary mathematics."/>
```

If anyone can help me resolve this issue so that it will post to the users wall, I would greatly appreciate it. I have looked at many other questions about the same problem, but everything I have tried has not worked.

Comment: I think it will be helpful if you add the code for the like button.

Comment: _“I know that my id is correct because my Facebook page is […]”_ – exactly, that’s a _page_. Administrators for Facebook plugins should be _user_ accounts.

Answer (score 1):

The fb:admin should not contain a random code but your (internal) facebook-id.

Go to http://www.facebook.com/insights and press the green 'statistics for your site' button. Then you wil see  how the fb:admin tag should be in your case.

Answer (score 0):

"fb:admins" must be your fb profile id ( not your fb profile name or your fb fanpage id )
You can get the fb profile id at https://graph.facebook.com/xxx. 
Change xxx to your profile name.
Find property "id"

Debug at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/